# Cron Won't Execute PHP

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I have been trying to execute PHP script using cronjob, but I can't get it to work. I've tried every solution I could find with no luck. Following is the process I am using:

```
sudo crontab -e

*/1 * * * * /user/bin/php /var/cron.php >> /var/log/cron.txt 2>&1
```

PHP script works when manually executed: (cron.php)

```
<?php 
 file_put_contents("output.txt", "Works");
?>
```

When I run a script which is not php it works, for example, the following script runs every 1 minute and works

```
*/1 * * * * touch /var/cron.txt >> /var/log/cron.txt 2>&1
```

If any of you can point out where I am going wrong I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Are there any error messages in `cron.txt`?

Comment: Nothing, Its empty. Timestamp updates every minute that is about it.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct directory for `output.txt`?

Comment: Try using an absolute pathname for the `output.txt` filename.

Comment: It should be in the same folder as cron.php, it is not there. I say that because that is where it shows up when I run the file manually

Comment: No, it will be in the user's home directory. That's the default working directory when running from `cron`.

Comment: You are right. That did it. Absolute path was what I was missing. Thanks Barmer, I really appriciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Barmar [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218303/cron-wont-execute-php#comment89417732_51218303), I was missing the absolute path for the output file in my script. Once I added that to my script file got created where I was expecting it to.